# API post request for microsoft Access token working in Postman but getting 404 Error from APIM

Tags: azure, api, azure-active-directory, azure-api-management, apim

I am requesting below endpoint url to get access token by passing client id, secret ,scope and grant type(x-www-form-urlencoded) and I can able to get the access token with Postman.
But When I'm requesting the same post request from APIM url, setting the below end point as backend url im getting 404 error.

Could you please suggest is there anything, we need to include in policies in APIM or any changes in the request ?

EndPoint url :
https://login.microsoftonline.com/***tenantID****/oauth2/v2.0/token

Error in APIM test result:
[image: Error in APIM test result]

Apim POST request:
[image: Apim POST request]

Comment: Could you please include the scope you are using?

Comment: Does this Url produce the error 404? https://login.microsoftonline.com/***tenantID****/oauth2/v2.0/token

Comment: Scope: https://**************.axcloud.dynamics.com/.default

Comment: APIM urL:  https://apim-********.azure-api.net/v1/apty/login                                                              APIM backend url :https://login.microsoftonline.com/***tenantID****/oauth2/v2.0/token

Comment: Can you share your policies?

Comment: @Markus Meyer                 Does this Url produce the error 404? login.microsoftonline.com***tenantID****/oauth2/v2.0/token –  No, i can get the access token with this url from postman, but setting this url as apim backend api im getting error

Comment: i have not included anything in the policies

Comment: ok, but this is too less information for me to reproduce it on my system

Comment: Are you missing a Content-Type header in the APIM policy?

        <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
            <value>application/x-www-form-urlencoded</value>
        </set-header>